# What do you think about this logo?

Tags: logo

[image]

This logo is from a fruit delivery service company and i would like to know what you guys think about it since im thinking about rebranding and changing the logo but i need a third party opinion to convince my boss to do so. The literal translation would be "Fruit in Home"

Answer (score 1):

To me the logo looks like it’s from a medical field or lawyers who went green, so I guess that could be a good argument for redesign. Something more soft and inviting can work, even if you guys only make letters a bit playful and maybe rounded.

One more thing, since it’s a delivery company feel free to add a sence of movement, which can be achived even with just using script/italic font. No need to change the whole concept, especially if your customers are older and long term.
Hope this helps!